# Global vs Local message processors

Tags: java, scope, global-variables, mule

I have a question related to the usage of the custom message-processors as Global vs local.

I have been defining all the custom transformers at global level and refered them in the mule flows.

What is difference in the scope of the object defined inside a flow versus one declared as global and referred in flow?

Is it going to be impact on the memory if a message processor is defined as global instead of inside flow?

Apart from reusability is there any benifit from defining the processors as global?

```
Ex:  
Global Way of defining: 

<custom-transformer name="mycustom" class="org.MyClass" />  
<flow name="myflow">
    ...
    ...
    <transformer ref="mycustom" />
    ...
    ...
</flow>


Local Way of defining:
<flow name="myflow">
    ...
    ...
    <custom-transformer name="mycustom" class="org.MyClass" />
    ...
    ...
</flow>
```

This information would be helpful in designing an optimal solution in terms of memory and code maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally defined transformers are declared as different beans in the registry so there is definitively a cost in declaring them locally again and again.

Thus prefer declaring similar transformers (and components, message processors...) globally.

Comment: What if a component is used only once. Does it make a difference in terms of memory of performance if I declare it Globally instead of Locally?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make a difference: in both cases this single component will end-up as a singleton in the registry.